# Redefinition of a variable Error

Tags: c++, eclipse

I've got 2 classes, casilla.cpp and casilla.h.

In the cpp one I get the error of class redefined, and in .h "there's a previous definition of the classs casilla. I've searched for it in the internet, but not even putting casilla:: before one or putting the headers work. Here's the code:

Casilla.h:

```
#ifndef CASILLA_H_
#define CASILLA_H_


using namespace std;

class Casilla { //previous definition of ‘class Casilla’
 public:
 casilla(); //ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘casilla’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 virtual ~casilla(); //expected class-name before ‘(’ token

 void SetNumeroCasilla (int _numero);
};

 /* namespace std */

#endif /* CASILLA_H_ */
```

Casilla.cpp:

```
  #include "Casilla.h"
   #include "Tablero.h"
   using namespace std;


#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
 class Casilla  //errors :Multiple markers at this line
- redefinition of ‘class Casilla’
- Line breakpoint: Casilla.cpp [line: 
 17]
{
int fila;
int columna;
int numero;

public:

  // default constructor
Casilla::Casilla()
: fila(-1)
, columna(-1)
, numero(0)
{ }

 int GetNumero() {return numero;}
void SetCasillaPosition (int _fila, int _columna) //set a cell position
  {
      fila = _fila;
      columna = _columna;
  }
void SetNumeroCasilla (int _numero)             //set a cell value
  {
      numero = _numero;
  }
 void SetCasillaFull (int _fila, int _columna, int _numero) //set a cell     position and value
    {
      fila = _fila;
      columna = _columna;
      numero = _numero;
   }

};
```

Just changed the code with new errors shown. The redefined error persists, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In casilla.cpp, you're redefining `casilla`... `class casilla { .. };` is a class definition, and you have it twice: once in your header and once in your cpp. Hence, the redefinition error.

All you need to do in the .cpp is provide definitions for the class methods you declared in your .h:

```
#include "Casilla.h"
// other includes

// define the default constructor:
casilla::casilla()
: fila(-1)
, columna(-1)
, numero(0)
{ }

// define this function
void casilla::SetNumeroCasilla (int _numero)
{
    // something
}
```

Comment: I did it but it shows some errors: I edit the OP with the new code and the errors in each line that appears

Comment: @flaixman You still have `class Casilla` in your cpp. Notice that my answer does not.